# Prometheus + Consul: Creating 2 targets for each Consul server (duplicating targets)

Tags: consul, prometheus

I'm using Prometheus + Consul for service discovery - an awesome combo. Among the services (targets, in prometheus's lingo) discovered by Consul there are the Consul servers themselves. This is useful - I want to monitor the servers too, not just Consul clients.

In fact, I wish to scrape these servers twice - essentially read metrics from *2 different ports* on each server.

I'm not sure how this can be achieved: I have no control over what Consul Servers expose to Prometheus about themselves.

Ideally, this could be performed with some regexp manipulation in Prometheus's configuration: I know how to drop a target from the list and I know how to mutate a target - but can a target be duplicated? is there some regex magic for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to create more targets. Instead have two scrape configs.

Comment: thanks, but that would complicate things: if I specify two scrape configs, I'll also have duplicate entries for every consul service (not just the servers).

just so its clear what I'm doing here: I'd like to scrape each server twice: once for the consul-exporter's metrics and again using telegraf (for the host metrics).

Comment: What you want then is three scrape configs. Two for the machine-level services, and one for the general services. Use relabelling to restrict what's scraped by each.